# Creating an empty Laravel model instance without attributes, but still get the id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Basically, I'm creating an Article instance:

```
$article = new Article();
//Returns null
$id = $article->id();
```

This however returns an empty object. What I would like to do is create an article and also get its id before doing:

```
$article->save();
```

Trying to create an article doesn't work, because it requires providing values or having default ones:

```
$article = Article::create();
```

The approach I'm thinking about is doing:

```
$latest_id = Article::latest()->first()->id;
```

But I'm not sure if it's the right one, or if there is a better method.

Comment: why do you need the 'id' before it is stored in the database?

Comment: What happen in multiple request for `Article::latest()->first()->id;` ? Suppose you get id no `5`,  then your next should be `6`.  but, in the same time other person input data in the same model. Then your id should be `7`„ right? But your controller know it would be `6`

Comment: @lagbox I need to use that id in naming some images I save for the article, then do some parsing, before creating the article itself.

Comment: @TalhaF. Yes, that's a problem. That's why I said it's not the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the ID of a Object / Model what you have not saved yet.

In this case the ID does not exist, you can find the latest ID and increase this ID by one, but then you could run in some race-condition, when another script what is also adding a new element to this Table is faster, then you have the wrong ID you save later.

If you need the ID to store References for this Model, the correct way would be to save the model first, and then save the references.

If you need the ID to save a file containing the ID in the filename, what you save then as text in the database you could first save the Model (to retrieve an ID), and then save the model with the missing informations again.

Comment: I guess I have no other option. I should save the model first to get its ID. Thank you. Accepted.

Comment: "I guess I have no other option" - don't feel defeated by this, it is a standard practice with frameworks :)

Answer (score 3):

The `id` is the value of the `id` column in data-base, and cause you did not save yet, there is nothing in data-base (and you can not get it).

I guess you need to do some tasks which could in some point fail or get cancelled, for which case there is a workaround, like:

```php
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $article = new Article();
    $article->fields = 'example';
    $article->save();

    // Anything needing ID here...

    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    // Handle or re-throw:
    throw $e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializing an empty model to get it's id won't help as the `id` is always calculated at the runtime. Remember that there could be `n` requests coming in the system at the same time.

You will need to make the fields in `nullable` if you want to create an empty row to get a reserved `id`.

Or if you only need the last id that is stored inside DB's table, you can do so by the following, but this can cause some mismatch and inconsistency in the data:

`$latest_id = Article::latest()->first()->id;`